# Have the prime Egyptian fractionary expansions of rational numbers been studied before?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, binary, egyptian-fractions

**Background**

In a 2018 [question posed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316474/can-we-write-each-positive-rational-number-as-frac1p-1-1-ldots-frac1p-k-1/446198#446198) by Zhi-Wei Sun, he conjectures that for any rational number $r>0$, there are finite sets $P_r^-$ and $P_r^+$ of primes such that
$$r=\sum_{p\in P_r^-}\frac1{p-1}=\sum_{p\in P_r^+}\frac1{p+1}. \tag{1}$$
Recently, Thomas Bloom has answered this question, and has published a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.02689) on the ArXiv in which a proof is presented that affirms this conjecture.

**Prime Egyptian Fractionary Expansions**

I'm currently considering a generalization of the representations presented in $(1)$. We could also consider powers of every term in the sum, resulting in a representation of the form: $$q = \sum_{p\in P_q^-}\frac{1}{(p-1)^{a_p}}=\sum_{p\in P_q^+}\frac{1}{(p+1)^{b_p}}. \tag{2} $$

Here, $|P_q^-| = l $ and $ |P_q^+| = m$. Also, $a_p$ and $b_p$ are positive integer numbers for all $p$. Then, the positive and negative Prime Egyptian Fractionairy Expansions$^{*}$ (PEFEs) are defined as $$q_{-} =  a_{p_l} \ a_{p_{l-1}} \ \dots \ a_{p_{2}} \ a_{p_{1}}, \tag{3} $$ and $$ q_{+} = b_{p_{m}} \ b_{p_{m-1}} \ \dots \ b_{p_{2}} \ b_{p_{1}}. \tag{4}$$

**Example**

For instance, we might have the following expansion: $$\frac{3}{8} = \frac{1}{(3-1)^{\color{red}3}} + \frac{1}{(5-1)^{\color{red}1}}. \tag{5} $$

Thus, we obtain the negative PEFE in positional notation: $$ \left( \frac{3}{8} \right)_{-} = \color{red}1 \ \color{red}3 \quad . \tag{6} $$

Also, we have $$\frac{3}{8} = \frac{1}{(3+1)^{\color{blue}1}} + \frac{1}{(7+1)^{\color{blue}1}}. \tag{7}$$

Here, we skipped the prime numbers $2$ and $5$ in the sum. We denote their corresponding $\quad$ powers as $\bar{0}$ in the (in this case, positive) PEFE: $$ \left( \frac{3}{8} \right)_{+} = \color{blue}1 \ \bar{0} \ \color{blue}1 \ \bar{0} \quad. \tag{8} $$

**Questions**

1. Have such prime Egyptian fractionary expansions of the form described in $(2) - (4)$ been described in the literature before?
2. Do they bear a relationship with the $p$-adic numbers, and if so, how can this relationship be characterized?

**Note**

(*) this name is a contraction of *Egyptian fraction* and *binary* (or ternary, or quaternary, etc.)

Comment: I like this question! Intuitively I don't expect there is a relationship with $p$-adic numbers, because they work with a single, fixed $p$ instead of running over all $p$. In a sense the name $p$-adic is misleading. My comment would sound more natural if I typed 'intuitively I don't expect there is a relationship with the 2-adic numbers.' And then a new comment 'Intuitively I don't expect there is a relationship with the 3-adic numbers'. And then so on and so on until I got automatically moved to chat

Comment: @Vincent Haha! Yes, I kind of had this suspicion as well. Do you think there is another number system these PEFEs might be more directly related to? Are there also "variable" p-adic numbers, that involve multiple different primes?

Comment: Encoding information as a sequence of numbers that should be interpreted as the powers of successive primes, is made famous by its use by Godel in his proof of his Incompletness Theorem. But the type of information he was encoding was quite different (and less directly related to the primes in question) than what happens in your question.

Comment: Hmm I only now realize that you do not look at powers of primes, but powers of numbers that are the neighbours of primes. I do not know of any place where that is used, but of course I do not know everything. I am curious what other answerers will say